# The fieldset isn't shown as collapsed

Tags: javascript, forms

I am writing a module that executes some queries, and returns the result in to a collapsed fieldset which is not shown as collapsed; I view its content. The collapse.js files are loaded.

This is the code I am using.

```
$body = $body . '<fieldset class="collapsible collapsed">' . 
  '<legend class="gestioneinterna">Viste aggiuntive</legend>' . 
  '<description class="description">fieldset extra.</description>' .
  '<div><p class="home_body "><a href="?q=vista_progetti_categoria/1"><strong>Vista progetti</strong></a></p></div>';
print $body;
```

Comment: You need to provide more information, preferably your not-working code. Otherwise, one could only guess what could be preventing collapsible to work as expected.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing a closing `</fieldset>` tag which probably won't be helping things, but I wouldn't advise doing it the way you currently are anyway.

A better way would be to make use of the [`theme_fieldset()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_fieldset/7) function like so:

```
// Make sure the collapsible library is loaded
drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.collapse');

// Build up the fieldset
$fieldset = array(
  '#theme' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => 'Viste aggiuntive',
  '#attributes' => array('class' => array('collapsible', 'collapsed')),
  '#description' => 'fieldset extra.',
  '#children' => '<div><p class="home_body "><a href="?q=vista_progetti_categoria/1"><strong>Vista progetti</strong></a></p></div></fieldset>'
);

// Add it to the body
$body .= render($fieldset);
```

That works great for me.

You might want to replace the call to `render()` above with `drupal_render()` as it offers a minute performance increase; I tend to use `render()` for all my calls for this sort of thing for continuity, and so that I don't have to check the type of the data being passed.

In this case, as you know the argument is not a string, you could save yourself the few microseconds and use `drupal_render()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following code for a quick test in a page callback, and it worked.

```
  drupal_add_js('misc/form.js');
  drupal_add_js('misc/collapse.js');

  $fieldset = array(
    '#attributes' => array(
      'class' => array('collapsible', 'collapsed'),
    ),
    '#title' => 'Viste aggiuntive',
    '#description' => 'fieldset extra.',
    '#children' => '<div><p class="home_body">' . l('<strong>Vista progetti</strong>', 'vista_progetti_categoria/1', array('html' => TRUE)) . '</p></div>',
  );

  return theme('fieldset', array('element' => $fieldset));
```

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

To notice that collapse.js needs form.js to work.
To be sure both the files are loaded, you can use `drupal_add_js()`; if the files are already added from a previous call to `drupal_add_js()`, they will not be added twice. Alternatively, you can replace those calls to `drupal_add_js()` with a call to [drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.collapse')](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_library/7). The code I wrote was written for a quick test just to verify I would have the same issue, but in general is preferable to call `drupal_add_library()` when there is a module that defines a specific library with [hook_library()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_library/7), for the fact `drupal_add_library()` loads all the dependencies (in this case, it would actually load both misc/collapse.js, and misc/form.js) without you know them beforehand. For a list of all the libraries defined from Drupal, see [system_library()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_library/7) (mainly), and [overlay_library()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!overlay!overlay.module/function/overlay_library/7) (secondarily); if one of the JavaScript files you need is listed there, it would be better to use `drupal_add_library()`.

Apart from the `<fieldset>` tag not being closed in your code, the other problem could be:

- The code doesn't use all the CSS classes the code in the collapse.js file depends upon. When I look at the HTML output from my code, I see the following. (I reformatted the code to make the single parts more evident.)

  ```
  <fieldset class="collapsible form-wrapper collapse-processed">
    <legend>
      <span class="fieldset-legend">
        <a class="fieldset-title" href="#"><span class="fieldset-legend-prefix element-invisible">Hide</span> Viste aggiuntive</a>
        <span class="summary"></span>
      </span>
    </legend>
    <div class="fieldset-wrapper" style="">
      <div class="fieldset-description">fieldset extra.</div>
      <div>
        <p class="home_body"><a href="/dr72/vista_progetti_categoria/1"><strong>Vista progetti</strong></a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  ```
- The form.js code is not loaded from the page you are outputting. This is could be the case, if you just added `drupal_add_js('misc/collapse.js')` to include the collapse.js file, or there is another module that used `drupal_add_js('misc/collapse.js')` without to use `drupal_add_js('misc/form.js')`.

As side note, when creating HTML output, it is better to use the functions Drupal provides; in this case, I used [theme_fieldset()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_fieldset/7), and [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7).
`l()`, in particular, outputs the correct URL. If you run the same code on a different server, such as one running on Windows, the URL would be always correct. That is also true when you move Drupal on a subdirectory of the root directory (which, in my case, is dr72); if you were to write the URL as you did, you would need to change the code you wrote (in the cases I reported), while using `l()` the code would not need to be changed. The same is true for [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7), which is the function used by `l()`.

Comment: Yes, thank you but now I need to add:
<legend class=\"gestioneinterna\"></legend>
because it's a class on my CSS for format title and other. Where can I insert it?

And now I need to view the result of some queries using fieldset.

Comment: And in which mode can I insert multiple fieldset?
If I copy the piece of the code, it returns only the first.

Comment: You need to call `theme('fieldset')` for each fieldset.

Comment: Replicate the code in your example n-times?

Comment: return theme('fieldset', array('element' => $fieldset)). theme('fieldset', array('element' => $fieldset));
It's ok in this way?

Comment: Yes, it is, as long as you use a different argument for each call to `theme('fieldset')`.

Comment: Is it possible to add more than one children in the fieldset?

Comment: You can just add a children, as `theme_fieldset()` uses the following code to add the children item: `$output .= $element['#children'];`. `$element['#children']` can be the HTML rendering more items, thought, which means the output of other theme functions, or `drupal_render()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a reference for people looking for simple Drupal fieldsets for their content - use render arrays! So much simpler & much cleaner to read.

The following snippet is a page callback function, that builds a fieldset that has a table inside it, with some sample data.

```
function mypage() {
  $build['myfieldset'] = array(
    'fieldset' => array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('Fieldset legend'),
      '#attributes' => array('class' => array('collapsible', 'collapsed')),
      'content' => array(
        '#theme' => 'table',
        '#header' => array('Col1','Col2','Col3'),
        '#rows' => array(
          array('Data 1-1','Data 1-2','Data 1-3'),
          array('Data 2-1','Data 2-2','Data 2-3'),
          array('Data 3-1','Data 3-2','Data 3-3'),
        ),
        '#empty' => t('No RFMs in this state'),
       ),
     ),
     '#attached' => array('js' => array('misc/collapse.js', 'misc/form.js')),
   );
   return $build;
 }
```